# Fill model field with default value instead of null

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have my model defined like this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Unknown")
```

`country` field is filled from JSON response, but sometimes is not available.

I am currently getting

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   explorer_api_activity.country

I have tried different combinations of `null=True`, `blank=True` and getting rid of the default, and also deleting migrations and the database, but to no avail.

I want to fill the field with "Unknown" whenever null is encountered. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default=None)
```

#### Update

If you insist on keeping your current model(not make the field nullable or have some string in it), then whenever you are saving your json data to model, make sure to store a string in country. Like this:

```
YourModel.objects.create(other_field='data', country=json_data.get('country', "Unknown"))
```

Currently, whenever you are saving the Model, when json data does not have country, you send `None` as parameter. That is why you are getting the `Not Null constrain error`.

Comment: Hmmm, but I want the default to be "Unknown". Also, isn't it a bad practice to use `null=True` with `CharField`: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html?

Comment: I don't think so. Nullable Charfield should be Null True. You can use blank true for Adminsite(or else you will face validation error of empty fields)

Comment: have you tried `country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='unknown')`

Comment: @Ruddra: OK. Anyway, your current solution fills `null` in the field. I need a string there, because when the model is serialized via API my other app cannot interpret `null`.

Comment: @Thanks ruddra, your solution will work, hence I am marking it as best answer. Still, I would prefer to have the logic in model, not view. I have posted another question where I hope to be more clear on what I want to achieve.